# condition modification in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to add redirects to .htaccess.

If the URL address does not contain /site/ or /builder/, redirect to /site/
Example:

```
http://www.mh.cz/test.php -> http://www.mh.cz/site/test.php
http://www.mh.cz/builder/a.php -> http://www.mh.cz/builder/a.php
http://www.mh.cz/site/contact.php -> http://www.mh.cz/site/contact.php
```

### Actualy .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mh.cz [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mh.cz/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mh\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mh.cz/site/$1 [L,R]
```

How to modify the condition to redirect be ignored if the URL already exists /builder/ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `.htaccess` redirect all pages to `index.php` or whatever you want.

In `index.php`, grab the requested URL and make conditions to determine which page to include depending on the URL.

For example, `http://www.example.com/test.php` will display content of  `http://www.example.com/site/test.php` but in the address bar `http://www.example.com/test.php` will remain, the user will not get `Error 404`.

I'm not sure if this will fulfill your actual need but it will work.